# Parse Migration Nightmare Missing semicolon before statement

Tags: ios, node.js, mongodb, parse-platform

I am having some issues getting my app migrated from Parse.  Here is what I have done so far:

Opened an mLab account and created a mongoDb.
Migrated data to that database.
Went to the Parse Server Example App page on github, downloaded it, and changed the directory to it.
Within the index.js of that file, I edited it to match my app using:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || ' mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@dsxxxxxx.mlab.com:#####/fritchchurch',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'fritchChurch',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'MYMASTERKEYWASHERE'
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  }
});
```

After this, I installed `npm` from terminal.
I then installed mongo for OS X, started the `mongod` service, then in a new window, ran `mongo`.

From here I ran the following in the same terminal window that I ran `mongo` from:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: fritchChurch" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"HerCell":1337, "title":"Sean Plott", "address":false}' \
http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/FritchDirectory
```

I then get this in terminal:

```
> -H "X-Parse-Application-Id": "fritchChurch" \
2016-10-06T10:23:11.818-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:3

> -H "Content-Type": "application/json" \
2016-10-06T10:23:11.819-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:3

> -d '{"HerCell":1337, "title":"Sean Plott", "address":false}' \
2016-10-06T10:23:11.821-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:3
```

What is going on?

Comment: to get the request on your parse server working, you need to start it (probably with node), and then you can make a curl request from your terminal that hits the server

Comment: @LulzCow I finally got it going but get this `[HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Failed to obtain name info for: [ (10.0.1.8, "nodename nor servname provided, or not known"), (10.0.1.8, "nodename nor servname provided, or not known") ]`

Answer (score 1):

You can to start your mongo instance and your parse server instance locally using these commands:

```
$ npm install -g parse-server mongodb-runner
$ mongodb-runner start
$ parse-server --appId APPLICATION_ID --masterKey MASTER_KEY
```

But since your DB is hosted on mLab, you probably don't need to start the mongo-runner.  You can try running the server only:

```
$ npm install -g parse-server 
$ parse-server --appId APPLICATION_ID --masterKey MASTER_KEY
```

You can follow the quick start guide [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Quick-Start).  Or the full guide [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Parse-Server-Guide).